# Why SessionFixationProtectionStrategy does not migrate session attributes?

Tags: spring, http, session, attributes, spring-security

```
rg.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy       - Invalidating session with Id '1Xih9jabIqjCtnNqIt1e6w__.node1' and migrating attributes.
2012-04-17 16:32:41,481 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-11) SESSION DESTROYED:   1Xih9jabIqjCtnNqIt1e6w__.node1
2012-04-17 16:32:41,482 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-11) NEW SESSION CREATED:    Mo0vId0MsOE6HS0+TQpZ6Q__.node1 of 3
```

Is there some way to turn off this SessionFixationProtectionStrategy or to fix migration of attributes, because it is not migrating the session attributes and this is breaking a lot of stuff?

Comment: What version of spring are you using? And could you show some configuration details?  Also, does no session attribute get migrated or some?

Answer (score 5):

Session fixation protection can be switched off using:

```
<http [...]>
    [...]
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
    [...]
</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or.. if you still needed to protect yourself from Fixation issues:

```
<bean id="concurrentSessionControlStrategy"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy"
  c:sessionRegistry-ref="sessionRegistry"
  p:maximumSessions="5"
  p:alwaysCreateSession="true"
  p:migrateSessionAttributes="true"
  p:exceptionIfMaximumExceeded="false"/>
```